# add a new column in multi index from the others

Tags: python, pandas, multi-index

```
In [151]: df
Out[151]: 
first        bar                 baz           
second       one       two       one       two 
A              1       2          3         4
B              5       6          7         8
```

My question is simple: from this df, how to create a new columns three which the sum of one and two columns ie get:

```
In [151]: df
Out[151]: 
first        bar                         baz           
second       one       two    three     one       two   three
A             1       2          3.        3.       4.     7. 
B             5       6          11.       7.       8.     15.
```

Thx.

Comment: Kindly provide your data as a dict: `df.to_dict()`

Comment: {('bar', 'one'): {0: 1, 1: 5},
 ('bar', 'two'): {0: 2, 1: 6},
 ('baz', 'one'): {0: 3, 1: 7},
 ('baz', 'two'): {0: 4, 1: 8}}

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is:

```
df1 = df.join(df.sum(level=0, axis=1))
```

which returns:

```
(bar, one)  (bar, two)  (baz, one)  (baz, two)  bar  baz
0           1           2           3           4    3    7
1           5           6           7           8   11   15
```

You can add this as well:

```
columns = [('bar', 'one'), ('bar', 'two'), ('bar', 'three'), ('baz', 'one'), ('baz', 'two'), ('baz', 'three')]
df1.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(columns)
print(df1.sort_index(level=0))
```

to have it in the format you asked for:

```
bar           baz          
  one two three one two three
0   1   2     3   4   3     7
1   5   6     7   8  11    15
```